# Getting files from FormData array in django backend

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I try to send POST request.

I try to post data (FormData) from javascript which contains array of images
The **print(request.data)** command in my console shows this:

```
 <QueryDict: 
     {'title': ['testTitle'], 'text': ['testText'], 
      'images': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 486217.jpg (image/jpeg)>, 
                 <InMemoryUploadedFile: 344611.jpg (image/jpeg)>, 
                 <InMemoryUploadedFile: default.png (image/png)>]
              }>
```

code in django :models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
text = models.TextField()
create_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow, blank=True, 
              null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title     

class ArticleImage(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='images', 
              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='article_images/')
    is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True,null=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow, blank=True, 
                  null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return  self.article.title
```

views.py

```
class ArticleMixinView(generics.GenericAPIView,
                    mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    ...)
serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
queryset = Article.objects.all()
lookup_field = 'id'


def post(self, request):
    print(request.data)
    new_article = Article.objects.create(title=request.data.get('title'), 
                  text=request.data.get('text'))
    new_article.save()
    for img in request.data.get('images'):
        # article_img = ArticleImage(article=new_article,img=File(img), 
        #                             is_main=False )
        # article_img.save()

    return Response({
            'article': ArticleSerializer(new_article, 
                       context=self.get_serializer_context()).data

    })
```

Creation of Article object works fine, but I got some problems with this array. What is wrong, or how I can get images from ***InMemoryUploadedFile*** objects ????
Please any help. Thank you in forward)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are sending `images` as an array from your front-end. You can format them a little better so that each object of array match your `ArticleImage` model. For example, each object of `images` key should have the file against `img` key (because that is name of your field in model):

```
<QueryDict: 
   {'title': ['testTitle'], 
    'text': ['testText'], 
    'images': [{'img': <InMemoryUploadedFile: 486217.jpg (image/jpeg)>},
             {'img': <InMemoryUploadedFile: 344611.jpg (image/jpeg)>}]
   }>
```

Now you can use a `ModelSerializer` with `many=True` to do the job for you.

For example, create a serializer for `ArticleImage` model:

```
class ArticleImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ArticleImage
        fields = ('article', 'img', 'is_main', 'create_time')
        read_only_fields = ('article', 'is_main', 'create_time') # so that only `img` field comes from input
```

Now use that to save your images in your model:

```
def post(self, request):
    print(request.data)
    images = request.data.pop('images')

    serializer = self.get_serializer_class(data=request.data) # why not use ArticleSerializer?
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)                 # this lets you validate if something is wrong with user's input
    new_article = serializer.save()                           # similar to Article.objects.create

    images_serializer = ArticleImageSerializer(data=images, many=True)  # only `img` comes from data
    images_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    images_serializer.save(article=new_article, is_main=False) # adding additional fileds

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

This code is not tested, let me know if something doesn't work properly. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think I do something wrong in my FormData creating method                           
        let data = new FormData(); 
        const {imgList}=this.state;
        
        data.append('title', event.target.elements.title.value,);
        data.append('text',event.target.elements.content.value,);
        imgList.forEach(i=>{
          data.append('images[]', i);
        })                                                                                                                                 Is this ok?